# Downloaded file keeps respawning after I delete it, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: downloads

first time on here. Novice user.

Downloaded a folder with a bunch of videos in it. When I move or delete the folder, it keeps reappearing in my downloads file and the videos inside it gradually recreate themselves as well. How do I stop this? Driving me insane.

Comment: A folder won't be created as the result of a download.  The folder would have to have been created by running something on your computer.  You'll have to include some details of what file you downloaded and what you did to activate or install the "file" (application) you downloaded.  This not only goes for Ubuntu, but it's the same with Windows and other Operating systems.

Comment: That does sound odd to me ... did you install some sort of sync program or backup program that is possibly "fixing" the moved or deleted folder? LD is also correct.. you would have had to create that folder to put movies in or extract a compressed file that had a folder in the structure .. How did you "Download" a folder (process)? from where?

Comment: No programs installed, just downloaded some video files. No other extraneous files.

Comment: I did use a torrent client, but this has never happened before with any other files from the same tracker.

Comment: The application that you are running, is this case, is a torrent client.  The downloaded files/folders are not performing this action.  The application that you are running is doing this.  The behavior and configuration of the particular application you are running (the torrent client) will depend on which torrent client you are using.  You'll find the folder behavior in your settings preference menu.

Comment: ok .. a torrent ... that's different ... my torrent downloader on windows will create a folder .. maybe your torrent client on Ubuntu made the folder and now you are Seeding it so when you delete it .. it downloads again so you can continue to seed

Comment: But the thing is I deleted the torrent on the torrent client and closed it. I also tried logging off and back on. No luck. I am using Deluge if that helps.

Comment: When you log in on a torrent, by default it will pickup where it left off.  The torrent clients, also by design, will do what it can to recover from flaws.  The action you are seeing is the applications effort to recover and continue the action you have started, even between reboots.

Comment: The torrent client is closed though. How do I stop this problem?

Comment: What is the name of the torrent client you are using?  The default torrent client for Ubuntu is `Transmission`.  If you didn't install a specific client, that is the one you are using.

Comment: The torrent client I am using is Deluge.

Comment: I'm formatting the answer which I'll post in about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quick solution for stopping the respawning of the folders

Uninstall deluge.

The problem you are having is with the application that you have installed.  From the comments, the application is **Deluge**.

You can stop the behavior by uninstalling the application that is creating the folders (**uninstall deluge**).  Or go into the menu of the specific application and manually cancel all the items in your active queue.

From question **first time on here. Novice user.**  The easiest resolution would be to remove **Deluge** and use the default bt torrent client that is already installed in Ubuntu and configured for ease of use.

From the [Ubuntu Documents page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo#Remove_all_torrents):

> Transmission is designed for easy, powerful use. We've set the
> defaults to Just Work and it only takes a few clicks to configure
> advanced features like watch directories, bad peer blocklists, and the
> web interface. When Ubuntu chose Transmission as its default
> BitTorrent client, one of the most-cited reasons was its easy learning
> curve.

The Torrent downloads will autmatically start just by clicking on the torrent filename.  You can also bring up the torrent interface by typing `torrent` in the Ubuntu search button.

The default screen will show all queues.  You can cancel any unwanted transfer or activity by clicking to select the transfer, then clicking the minus sign in the menu bar.

I performed research on Deluge but didn't find definitive answers for cancelling a download.  Out side of actually installing it myself, the resolution may be the same as with **Transmission** in Ubuntu.  Select the tranfer and use the menu option to remove the item.

Support for Deluge specific can be found at [Deluge Support Forum](https://forum.deluge-torrent.org/).

Comment: I have already tried purging, using autoremove, and reinstalling the program. No luck.

Comment: @Matt Reinstalling the program would bring the problem back.  My suggestion is for you to purge it and not use it.  Use the default Bit Torrent client (Transmission) which doesn't have that problem.  Purging the client will remove the systemwide configuration.  It won't remove the settings that are in your personal space... which is likely the source of the problem.

Comment: Problem oddly stopped occurring randomly. Thanks for the help.